# Delete from all tables by a particular ID

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I've searched over SO, but many questions are related to truncating the tables, but I don't want to empty the tables, I need to delete from **all** tables, perhaps with one query instead of multiple queries.

So far I have 34 tables in my database, I need to delete all rows that have an a particular ID when requested. For example:

```
DELETE FROM table1, table2 ... table33, table34
WHERE customer_id = 4
```

How do I go ahead with a query that can do this? On another thought, all tables may not have rows that is same to the `customer_id`, so it should delete even there are no records with an ID of `4`.

Comment: Do all tables have a `customer_id` column?

Comment: Because they do, I have cloned sites, they refer to the customer ID, but I cannot tell you why but they all do for reasons. The reason why I need to do this because I'm in control of cloned sites, I have the power to disable, delete and edit them. So when I delete the cloned site, it should delete all rows to the ID of the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't find this is because you shouldn't really need it.  I don't think there is a way to do this because usually you don't have to if you properly use [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).  The proper way to maintain this is to have your foreign key constraints set up so they point from tables which have your customer id (ex customer_purchase) to the table where custom_id is the primary key; and then when you delete a customer from the table where customer_id is the primary key; all other tables referring to that customer will also be deleted.

Building from what I just mentioned; a lot of people choose to do a "soft" delete.  This is where you just set a flag on the customer table and then simply set it to "1" when it is deleted.  The reason you might want to do this is for audit-ability reasons.  Say, for example, you need to keep a record of all purchases; even when a customer is deleted.  In this situation; you should do soft deletes so you don't lose items from your purchase history when your customer is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is acceptable solution for you, but you can you

```
DELETE t1, t2, ... FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, ...
WHERE t1.customer_id = 4 AND t2.customer_id = 4 AND ...
```